# How can I pass one-dimentional array to php page using JQuery and Ajax?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I have one-dimentional array that is filled and drained according to change on checkboxes. In order to demonstrate the schema, my array is as following:

arrReservedSeats = ["1A", "3B", "5C", ...]

I want to use this array in php side to store them in database after some operations. The ajax part of my javascript function which is triggered by "Purchase" button is as follows:

Ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
           url:  'makePurchase.php',
           type: 'POST',
           dataType: 'text',
           data: {"arrResSeats" : arrReservedSeats}
           })
             .done(function(response) {

               if(response == "success")
               {
                 //..
               }
               else if(response == "failure")
               {
                 //..
               }
             })
               .fail(function(jqXHR, status, error) {

                  alert(jqXHR.response);
               })
                 .always(function(){
                    //..
                 });
```

I am not interested on returning some data to javascript side, so I just used the way to return data as 'text'.

makePurchase.php:

```
if(isset($_POST["arrResSeats"]))
  echo("<script>console.log('PHP: ".$_POST["arrResSeats"]."');</script>");

// Database operations...

if(//operations are okay)
   echo "success";
else
   echo "failure";
```

The problem is, I can not communicate with my php page through ajax (I can, if I just send a single variable, without using json but in this case, I need to pass an array). Thanks for your interest!

NOTE: I have examined almost every related link on Stackoverflow but I could not make any of them useful in my project.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194843/discussion-on-question-by-bbasaran-how-can-i-pass-one-dimentional-array-to-php-p).

Answer (score 1):

I agree, probably should be working.  It you are getting something other than a 200 status code, like a 404 or 500, there is probably an error with the URL to you PHP page, or something wrong with the PHP page itself.  I tried it on my server and it does look like it works, although $_POST["arrResSeats"] is already an array.  You should not have to decode it.

If I put:

```
<?

$arrResSeats = $_POST["arrResSeats"];

print_r($_POST["arrResSeats"]);


?>
```

on the php page I get:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1A
    [1] => 3B
    [2] => 5C
)
```

I am not sure you even have to Stringify and then Parse on the HTML page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <meta name="generator" content="BBEdit 11.6" />
    <link rel="icon" href="data:,">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script>

arrReservedSeats = ["1A","3B", "5C"];

  $.ajax({
           url:  'purchase.php',
           type: 'POST',
           dataType: 'text',
           data: {"arrResSeats" : arrReservedSeats}
           })
             .done(function(response) {

               if(response == "success")
               {
                 //...
               }
               else if(response == "failure")
               {
                 //...
               }
             })
             .fail(function(jqXHR, status, error) {

                  alert(jqXHR.response);
             })
             .always(function(){

                  //...
             })

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

You might be able to also just pass a JSON string as the value for arrResSeats, or ResSeatsJSON (rename) and then decode that on the PHP page.

Comment: Agreed on “json_decode” and “parse/stringify”. I also think this could be an apache setting, I.e: he’s sending a too many information in the JSON object and apache is blocking the request.

Comment: First of all, I get "200" status code and there is nothing wrong in path php file also. That is a bit weird in this context. "I am not sure you even have to Stringify and then Parse on the HTML page." I completely agree on your words, I thought same at first but in stackoverflow, I read a lot of comments that advises to use json in posting array.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make the problem more comprehensible:
When I trigger my other ajax functions (they work properly), network tab is as shown below:

[My other correct functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqbJR.png)

However, when I try this one, result is not the one which it is supposed to be:

[The problematic one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q87ju.png)
(Just this, there is no more operation in network tab)

As you see, there is no "POST" operation. I am using this function as same as the other(proper) ones. I can not see any difference so that is weird for me.

Comment: So does the AJAX handler even fire at all (apparently not).  Did you look at the Console to see if there is a JS error or other error that is preventing the handler from firing.  From what you are saying it sounds like you never even POST the data.  You might just have a syntax error ?  There is a closing } in your first post that does not look like it belongs there (the last one).

Comment: @sscotti After you mentioned that you could properly use, I revised my code to the way which is not using JSON. I updated my first message, do you mind if ask you to check it, please? I can not see any syntax error.

Comment: Not sure what the issue is then.  The 2 pieces of code that I posted work for me.  One is the HTML page, the other is the PHP page.  You should be able to use the inspector in web tools to see:  1). If the handler is even attached to your button or whatever it is that you have.  The image you showed looks like it making a GET request to the page ?  That sort of suggests that the AJAX call is not even being made.  The code that I posted works fine on my sever, which is MAMP running on a Mac using PHP 7.x.

Comment: @sscotti I solved the problem thanks to the effort to help here. You were right, there was no need to use Json. Simple text response was enough. Thanks again!